# how to pass header attribute from file outbound adapter to transformer

Tags: spring-integration, dsl

I am using file outbound adapter to read files and pass them through a series of transformers using spring integration DSL and noticed that file names are are not accessible from these transformers.
How can i pass the initial file names in the below:

```
IntegrationFlows.from(Files
            .inboundAdapter(new File(this.props.getIndir()))
            .autoCreateDirectory(true)
            .preventDuplicates(true)
            .patternFilter(this.props.getFilePattern()),
            e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000L)))


            ...

            .transform(Transformers.converter(fileConverter))
            ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to show your transformer code; you can either pass in discrete headers using `@Header` annotations...

```
public Result transform(@Payload File foo, @Header("...") String bar, ...)
```

or simply pass in the whole `Message<?>` so you can access the headers...

```
public Result transform(Message<File> message)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot really appreciate it.